# Linear Array Output Issue?

Tags: java, arrays

This is one of my first java programs, which includes a GUI and an linear array (I hope!)

I know this isn't suppose to be a 'help' website but more of a place to collaborate
ideas, but I've been staring my eyes out for the past hour and a half with little to no progress on my problem (which I will get too momentarily) The funny being it's probably not even the hardest bit of the program.

So I'm hoping you guys can help me figure this out. I've created a fairly simple program that most I've already written, and after completion of the program the user can input a number in (enterNumberField) choosing numbers from the linearArray (1, 2, 31 or 35) and after pressing a button, the program outputs either A, B, C or D in the textField I've dubbed 'ItsAField' (creative I know).

Unfortunately, no matter what number is chosen it always outputs as D.

```
public class ChildrensClassicsView extends FrameView {

    String [] linearArray = {"1", "2", "31", "35"}; //numbers to choose from

}

    static public Boolean linearSearch (String [] A, String B) {
        for (int k=0; k<A.length; k++) {
            if (A[k].equals(B)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

After pressing action performed button...

It wouldn't surprise me if it was just a problem with these 'if statements' however I'm not even sure if you can use them like this to get the answer I'm looking for. Am I on the right track for outputting the 'chosen' variable?

```
    private void findButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

String input = enterNumberField.getText();

if (input.equals("1")) {
        ItsAField.setText("Search: A " + linearSearch(linearArray, "1"));
    }
    if (input.equals("2")) {
        ItsAField.setText("Search: B " + linearSearch(linearArray, "2"));
    }
    if (input.equals("28")){
        ItsAField.setText("Search: C " + linearSearch(linearArray, "31"));
    } else {
        ItsAField.setText("Search: D " + linearSearch(linearArray, "35"));
    }
```

I also have my figures crossed hoping this still qualifies as a real question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to compare `String` values with the `==` operator, but in Java, for objects (including `Strings`), this compares the object references to determine if they refer to the same object.

To compare `String` values, use [`String#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
if (input.equals("1")) {
```

**EDIT**

The question changed.  It used to be an `if` followed by 2 `else-if`s followed by an `else`, with each one using `==` attempting to compare `String` values.

Now it is 3 `if` statements, with only the last one having an `else`, even if they're all using `equals` now.

Restore the `else` before the 2nd and 3rd `if` statements.  They should be `else if` statements.

```
if (input.equals("1")) {
    ...
}
else if (input.equals("2")) {  // else restored here
    ...
}
else if (input.equals("28")){  // else restored here
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

This way, exactly one conditional block is executed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However after modifying the code, the problem still is present.

Comment: For some reason you took out your `else`s before the middle 2 `if`s.  See my update.  Restore the `else`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare strings with [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) not `==`

So change the if statements to `if("1".equals(input))`